# Typing the 'e' key brings the emoji menu

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flex3, macos-monterey

I have an Air app that is basically a wrapper for my swf RIA.
On the Mac, since updating to MacOS 12 (Monterey) today, typing the letter 'e' in any textbox /rich text box field brings the Emoji menu instead. In a similar way, 'd' brings the dictation menu.
This has been reported by 3 users in a couple of hours and I was able to reproduce it by upgrading my Mac to Monterey.
I toyed with the keyboard shortcuts in the OS settings, but no luck.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report instead of a programming question. Make a [post on the AS3 Runtime Issues page](https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues). Also check if a similar problem has been asked/resolved there.

Comment: Check: [StageText triggering Emojis & Symbols window on Mac OS Monterey #1323](https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/1323).